# Как реализовать логику попап окон ?

Tags: html, javascript

Добрый день, у меня вопрос - сделал на `js+html` всплывающее окно, в нем функционал. Но тут оказалось, что окон будет много... Как лучше быть в такой ситуации: написать много окон и показывать их `display:block;` и скрывать их `display:hide;` или же это как-то можно реализовать в 1ом окне, каким то магическим образом подменивая в нем контент?

Приведу пример:

```
<div class="popup newaction">
<div>

<div class="popup print">
<div>

<div class="popup info">
<div>
```

Comment: z-index может помочь управлять видимостю блоков.

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от того, чем различаются окна. 
Если, допустим, они отличаются только контентом (например, там есть заголовок и текст) и цветом, то логично сделать один блок и описать его.

[Вот пример на JQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/LKP97/2/).
Соответственно прятать попап можно с помощью

```
$('#popup').hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

Все уже давно написано) Воспользуйтесь либой [Colorbox](http://www.webappers.com/2009/03/06/colorbox-customizable-lightbox-plugin-for-jquery/)

Можно создавать попап любой сложности с любым контентом

Answer (score 0):

Если может быть только одно открытое окно, и окна одинаковые, то конечно лучше заменять только контент. Например хранить контент в скрытых блоках и вставлять в попап.

```
$("#popup").html($("#hiddenDiv1").html())
```

Если контента много, его можна хранить в отдельных страницах и подгружать ajax-ом

```
$("#popup").load("page1.html", function() { openPopup() })
```

Одно окно экономит размер страницы и будет удобно поправлять стили

Но если конечно, все окна будут разными, или могут быть открытыми в один момент времени, тогда нужно делать отдельные попапы.